# Django Send_Mail Value Error

Tags: django, email, model, django-queryset

I am struggling to use a QuerySet as an recipient arguement for the send_mail function

I have this model:

```
class Group(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(primary_key=True)
  mailing_list = models.ManyToManyField("Customer", null=True)  

class Customer(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField()
  email = models.EmailField(primary_key=True)
```

I want to email the mailing_list for a specific group. I can access this via

```
mailList = list(Customer.objects.filter(group__name='group_two').values_list('email'))
```

However when I put mailList in my send_mail function I get a

```
Value Error: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

When I look at the mailList variable it looks like

```
[{email: u'someonesname@domain.com'}, {email: u'anothername@domain.com'}]
```

Any ideas? Thank you

PS. I've looked at [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2551353/django-send-mail-from-queryset) already but its not really helpful to me

**Figured It Out**

After four hours of messing around with code I finally got it.

```
mailing_list = []

for contact in Customer.objects.filter(group__name='group_two'):
  mailing_list.append(contact.email)
```

Comment: This may work in one step, but it's not tested: `mailing_list = Customer.objects.filter(group__name='group_two').values_list('email', flat=True)`

Answer (score 0):

There may be a better way, but you can try this:

```
list = []
for customer in Customer.objects.filter(group__name='group_two').values_list('email'):
    list.append(customer.email)

send_mail('<Subject>', '<Message>', 'from@example.com', list, fail_silently=False)
```

Comment: Thank you but that gives me a "'list' object is not callable" error

Comment: Ah, the error occurs trying to call `list()` with `Customer.objects...` Leave that part out as edited and it should work, but I see you figured that out, already. :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
[{email: u'someonesname@domain.com'}, {email: u'anothername@domain.com'}]
```

it looks like you check this list:

```
list(Customer.objects.filter(group__name='group_two').values('email'))
```

with values_list:

```
list(Customer.objects.filter(group__name='group_two').values_list('email'))
...
[(u'someonesname@domain.com',), (u'anothername@domain.com',)]
```

and for values_list with flat=True:

```
list(Customer.objects.filter(group__name='group_two').values_list('email', flat=True))
...
[u'someonesname@domain.com', u'anothername@domain.com']
```

check documentation
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values_list